# AngularJS click directive doesn't trigger function w/ Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, pug

This is loosely based on the [MEAN Stack demo](http://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2013/05/12/how-to-easily-validate-any-form-ever-using-angularjs/): Mongo, Express, AngularJS, and NodeJS

I want to add a `delete` method to my controller in my Jade template like so

***characters.jade***

```
script
    function CharactersController($scope, $http, $window){
        $scope.charactersList = [];

        $scope.newCharacter = {};

        $scope.init = function(charactersList){
            $scope.charactersList = charactersList;
        }

        $scope.save = function(form){

        }

        $scope.delete = function(id){
            console.log('delete: '+id);
        }
    }
body
    h1  Characters
    div(ng-controller="CharactersController", ng-init="init( #{JSON.stringify(charactersList)} );") Create a new character:
        br
        form(name="charactersForm", ng-submit="save(charactersForm)")
            input(type="string", ng-model="newCharacter.firstName", name="firstName", placeholder="Firstname...")

            input(type="submit")
        hr
        div(ng-repeat="character in charactersList.characters")
            {{character.lastName}}, {{character.firstName}} - Quantity: {{character.quantity}} 
            button(ng-click="delete('{{character._id}}')") remove`
```

I believe I'm just screwing up the `scope` of the `ng-click` as the `delete(...)` function isn't triggering even though it's within the `ng-controller="CharactersController" div?

Answer (score 1):

What does the final output of the jade template look like? Haven't used jade but maybe the `ng-click` isn't converted to html correctly since it's not a standard attribute.
Also any errors in the console? I would also try `ng-click="alert('the click handler works')"` to try and isolate the issue.

Comment: so here is the output: `<div ng-repeat="character in charactersList.characters" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Baucke, Jordan - Quantity: 2 <button ng-click="alert('hi');">remove</button></div>` looks right to me, but the JS `alert` doesn't fire?

Comment: Are you initialising angilar properly? eg: by using  <html ng-app="myAppName"> Check the http://angularjs.org/ home page example.